# Arrange by a dynamically specified column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying use the `arrange()` function from `dplyr` but specify the column dynamically.

Here is a reprex:

```
dt <- tibble(
  foo = 1:10,
  bar = 101:110
)

sort_by <- 'bar'

dt %>% arrange(sort_by) # does not work

dt %>% arrange(!!quo_name(sort_by)) # does not work either
```

What is the correct way to pass a dynamic column name to `arrange()`?

Comment: Hi, I tried the example you posted and it seem to work on my R studio and R desktop (version 4). Best

Comment: I am using R 3.6.3 and it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `get`

```
dt %>% arrange(get(sort_by))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are 5 approaches to pass string variables in `arrange`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
```

1. `arrange_at`

```
dt %>% arrange_at(sort_by)
```

2. `across` - `_at` verbs are deprecated so we can use `across` from `dplyr` 1.0.0 instead.

```
dt %>% arrange(across(all_of(sort_by)))
```

3. Using non-standard evaluation with `sym` and `!!`.

```
dt %>% arrange(!!sym(sort_by))
```

4. Using `.data` pronoun

```
dt %>% arrange(.data[[sort_by]])
```

5. Latest addition is function `pick`

```
dt %>% arrange(pick(all_of(sort_by)))
```